# Send text and image to php with java

Tags: java, php, string, image

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so if you have any comment on the way I put/explain it, I would gladly accept any pointers.

So here it is:

I want to sent both text and an image to a php script on a server. I can succesfully sent both apart from each other, but not together. Up till now I use this for a String:

```
String dataSend = URLEncoder.encode("User","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8");
URL url = new URL(urlCopyImage);            
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());    
out.write(dataSend);
out.close();
```

For a image I use:

```
URL url = new URL(urlCopyImage);            
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
ImageIO.write(image,"PNG", connection.getOutputStream());
```

Can i somehow combine these two?

In the php script I merely use the `$_POST` to receive the string and for the image i use:

```
$incomingData = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Any tips are welcome.

For the record, I use the php file to create a file containing this image on the server. The username is useful for specifying the directory.

EDIT:

Thanks to your answers I have been able to make it work, though I don't quite understand it yet.

```
    MultipartEntity multipart = new MultipartEntity();
    multipart.addPart("User", new StringBody(username));
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", os);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
    ContentBody cb = new InputStreamBody(is, "something.png");
    multipart.addPart("Image", cb);

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlCopyImage);
    post.setEntity(multipart);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

I am handing the contentbody a inputstreambody which get the bytestream from the ImageIO. That's great. But what i don't get is what the second parameter of the inputstreambody is supposed to do. Although this works, it feels not right.

Btw, this is the php code:

```
$user = $_POST['User'];
copy($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'],$filename);
```

I would be grateful if someone could explain what exactly I'm doing here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Apache HTTP client to make a POST request with mime type multipart/form-data, and add parts for both the binary data and the text.

On the PHP side, you can read the file via $_FILE

See this blog post I wrote some time ago http://zybnet.com/java-http-client-and-post-requests/

Comment: This is really helpful. Now I just need to figure out how to convert my BufferedImage in some kind of stream.

Comment: You don't necessary need an [InputStreamBody. Check the API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) may help. It show how to use ImageIO in the javax.imageio package

Comment: You may need help to (transfer the content of an OutputStream into an InputStream](http://ostermiller.org/convert_java_outputstream_inputstream.html). There are multiple options: an in-memory byte array (and you'll likely use a ByteArrayBody), a temporary file, multiple threads with piped in/output streams and finally a circular byte buffer